# How should I refer to my master's thesis in its text? A paper?

Tags: thesis

Occasionally I need to refer to my master's thesis itself in its text, e.g. in the sentence "These rules are sufficient to compute any differential in this ____".

I was wondering which of the following terms are appropriate to fill the gap: paper, thesis, text, work.

Comment: Dissertation is another widely used term.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a paper because this term usually denotes journal articles.

You can use the term *thesis* or the more generic *work*, instead.

Answer (score 3):

I personally referred to mine as a study, or more specifically "the current study" (text or work would fit as well). This was you can avoid using the first person. 
Examples:

- the aim of the current study was to...
- Smith *et al* demonstrated that.... which is in agreement with the findings of the current study
- Results of the current study challenge the notion that...

Answer (score 2):

***Thesis*** and ***work*** are widely used terms. I would use *thesis* to refer to the text itself, and *work* to refer to the actual work that has been done, prior to the writing, which is reported in the thesis; e.g. the experiments, implementation, process, etc.

***Text*** would also be correct but I have not encountered it very often in the context of science and engineering.

I have also seen the term ***book*** used for this purpose. Usually this is within theses of which many copies are printed as books and circulated.

I would argue that *paper* is not a correct term to refer to a thesis.

Answer (score 0):

"document" seems to be a good general solution.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE. Would you care to expand on your answer a bit?